# Is there a possiblity of accessing shadowed global variable using document or window object ( or any way )?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

Is there any possible method/ways to access a globally declared variable inside a function which is shadowed by parameters or local variable ??

```
var x = 10; //globally declared variable

(function abc(x){     // shadowing of x using parameter with same name
   console.log(x);    // prints 11  - Can I access globally declared x inside this function?
})(11)
```

Comment: Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? *In general* it's not possible. *In this specific case* there is a workaround by using `window.x` but only in a browser. Overall, it seems like you should be looking for a way to avoid the shadowing.

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe*.

In a browser, non-module context, top level variables declared with `var` are assigned as properties of the `window` object. So you might be able to access it with `window.x`.

Best practise is to avoid shadowing. I'm fond of using the [no-shadow rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow) with ESLint to catch accidental shadowing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `globalThis` (added in ES2020)

```js
globalThis.x = 10;

(function abc(globalThis){     // shadowing of x using parameter with same name
   console.log(x);    // prints 10
})(11)
```